# Returning photos from Instagram by hashtag to my ios app

Tags: ios, instagram

I have an app in which I want to have **10 UIImage** objects that hold first **10** images by hashtag ***#clock***. What is the best way to do this? And do I have to authorize into **Instagram**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/) using `NSURLConnection`. The API endpoints will return you responses in JSON format. You will then need to parse those responses using something like `NSJSONSerialization`. Pick the image URLs from the response and create `UIImage` instances from them.

You won't need to authenticate for most of the API calls, but you will need to request a client ID. Looks like you could use the `tags/tag-name/media/recent` endpoint of the Instagram API for what you are trying to do.